# out parameter with struct c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, parameters

I am trying to poll a photocell. the code executes as it should but the struct values aren't changing after the first call to the method

```
int i = ConnectSendersByIP(ip);

std::cout << "Connected Senders: " << i << std::endl;

int j = ConnectReceivers();

std::cout << "Connected Receivers: " << j << std::endl;

WORD u = GetSenderId((byte)0);


receiverStatus_v1 * rsptr;


while (true)
{
    std::cout << "Polling Photocell" << std::endl;

    BOOL rd = GetReceiverDiagnostics_v1(u, (byte)0, 0, rsptr);

    std::cout << rd << std::endl;

    WORD brit = rsptr->bwEnviBritValue.GetWord();

    WORD lum = GetLumAttenuation();

    std::cout << "LUX: " << ((brit * lum) / 100) << " \r\n BRIT: " << brit << "\r\n LUM:" << lum << std::endl;

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Here is the method declaration in the header file

```
BOOL phcellmethod(WORD senderId, BYTE portIndex, WORD receiverIndex, _Out_ somestruct* pReceiverStatus);
```

in the somestruct struct there is another struct that stores the data from the photocell.

```
    struct anotherstruct
{
    BYTE hi;
    BYTE lo;
    WORD GetWord() const
    {
        return (hi << 8) + lo;
    }
};
```

I am primarily a .NET programmer, i am a bit unfamiliar with pointers in c++. How can i call this method and have the data in the struct change in every cycle of the loop?

Comment: Did you initialize the photocell correctly? How is the phcellmethod specified?
By the way, you don't need the pointer variable rsptr, you can just pass &rs to the phcellmethod.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @PasserBy I am unable to provide the complete source code. The photocell uses a proprietary DLL /LIB file that I cannot share/have access to.

Comment: @tangoal farther up in the code I can successfully connect to the photocell. I changed the method declaration to accept a reference. It still does the same thing. the struct is filled with the initial read then all subsequent reads are not overwriting the phcell substruct.

Comment: Nitpick maybe but this looks like C, not C++ (you may be compiling with a C++ computer like MSVC++ but the posted code and API do not leverage any C++ features).

Comment: ... Except for the std::cout of course, haha. But the photocell API is still C.

Comment: @TypeIA You are correct. the API is in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WORD brit = (*rsptr).phcell.GetWord();
```

or

```
WORD brit = rsptr->phcell.GetWord();
```

should be the syntax you want. Either, you dereference the pointer using `*` or use `->`

Comment: The dot method throws an error " expression must be of class type"

The other one compiles and executes but the values are not changing. The initial read is filling the struct but all other reads are being ignored. I verified this by starting the exe with the photocell detecting the ambient light, then a covered the photocell with my hand. The values should drop in value, but the initial values remain.

Comment: You'd need to do `(*rsptr).phcell.GetWord()` in the first example

Comment: I was able to get it working. I have to reconnect to the photocell every polling cycle. This API sucks.